# Incorrect where indentation? Short code

Tags: haskell, where-clause, shortcode

I tried to make a very short code, because we have a reglementation that favors the shortest code.
We have to create a function that turns a list into a new list of ascending and descending lists in the same order: For example. `[1,6,2,1,7,3,2,8,4]`, becomes `[[1,6],[2,1],[7],[3,2],[8],[4]]`

So i tried to do the following:

```
func :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
func xs = f1 d [a]
f1 [] ys = [c]
f1 xs ys    | a >= b = d `f1` a:ys
            | otherwise = c: d `f2` [a]
f2 [] ys = [c]
f2 xs ys    | a < b = d `f2` a:ys
            | otherwise = c : d `f1` [a]
    where   a = head xs
            b = head ys
            c = reverse ys
            d = tail xs
```

But i get

```
parse error on input '='
```

on the `line "b = head ys"`.

I thought it is possible to define multiple functions in the where block?

Other indentations created errors like a lot of

```
not in scope 'a'
not in scope 'b'
not in scope 'c'
not in scope 'd'
```

or

```
parse error on input 'b'
```

I have to make it that way to save some tokens/ have shorter code.

Comment: Tabs? If yes, kill them with fire.

Comment: Who has asked you for such short code, amd why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error messages are because you're mixing tabs and spaces. It's best to just use spaces.

Now, if you're writing

```
a = head xs
b = head ys
c = reverse ys
d = tail xs
```

then

```
xs = (a:ds)
ys = (b:es)
```

Let's rewrite your function with pattern matching:

```
func :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
func [] = []
func (a:ds) = f1 ds [a]
f1 [] ys = [reverse ys]
f1 (a:ds) (b:es) | a >= b = ds `f1` (a:b:es)
                 | otherwise = reverse (b:es): ds `f2` [a]
f2 [] ys = [reverse ys]
f2 (a:ds) (b:es) | a < b = ds `f2` (a:b:es)
                 | otherwise = reverse (b:es) : ds `f1` [a]
```

I know this is longer, but bear with me. `f1` is really the same as `f2`, but with the comparison changed. Let's get a function `no` to negate a comparison, so that `(no (>=)) x y = not (x >= y)`:

```
no cmp x y = not (cmp x y)
```

In fact, we can write this as

```
no = ((not.).)
r = reverse

func' (a:ds) = f (>=) ds [a]
f :: Ord a => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
f _ [] ys = [r ys]
f cp (a:ds) ys@(b:es) | cp a b = f cp ds (a:ys)
                      | True = r ys : f (no cp) ds [a]
```

Now that *is* shorter.

Comment: Interesting solution, i thought of an solution packing the f functions into one changing the compare, but couldn't solve it, because i am just a beginner. ^^
Thank you for this.

Comment: Ah i just found out, that i have to change the >= to <=. That was something i had wrong.
Only problem here. The no function now turns the >= to < and not to <=

Comment: OK, pass a `Bool`, not an `a -> a -> Bool` and use `not` instead of `no`. Next replace the guard `| cp a b` with `| leq cp a b` and separately define `leq True = (<=)` and `leq _ = (>=)`. Finally, `func'' (a:ds) = f False ds [a]`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a more fundamental problem than indentation: a `where` block is local to a *single* function case. You're trying to use your `where` block to provide bindings (e.g. `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) to a whole bunch of functions. This won't work.

To clarify, this *correctly indented* code won't work:

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo 0 = a
foo 1 = b
  where a = 2
        b = 3
```

You'll get an error like `` Not in scope: `a' ``. This is because the `where` only extends over the `foo 1` case; it doesn't even go to the `foo 0` case, much less any other function.

Your code, on the other hand, seems to expect the `where` block to work for *all* your functions. To have bindings that can be seen by different functions, you have to put them at the same level of scope as the functions themselves.

Also, Haskell indentation is a little finnicky. You really should avoid tabs; it also really helps to have an editor that understands Haskell properly. I've found Emacs is very good here--I never have to worry about Haskell indentation with Emacs.

Emacs might have a bit of a learning curve (you should do the tutorial), but I think it's well worth it. You'll also have to install the Haskell mode. If you get the newest version of Emacs, you should be able to do this using the package manager.

Comment: @AndrewC: Haha, I meant *tabs*, not *spaces*. Good catch. Ultimately, you should just avoid indenting stuff manually if you can avoid it :).

Answer (score 2):

That's how it looks to the compiler:

```
func :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
func xs = f1 d [a]
f1 [] ys = [c]
f1 xs ys    | a >= b = d `f1` a:ys
                | otherwise = c: d `f2` [a]
f2 [] ys = [c]
f2 xs ys    | a < b = d `f2` a:ys
                | otherwise = c : d `f1` [a]
            where    a = head xs
                        b = head ys
                        c = reverse ys
                        d = tail xs
```

So for the compiler, the lines in the where clause after the first look like continuations of that line, and of course you can't have multiple `=` without an intervening semicolon on one line.

You should **never** mix tabs and spaces (you shouldn't ever use tabs, actually). And if you use tabs, configure your editor to interpret them as eight spaces.

And, the `where` clause only scopes over the last equation, so there are no `a, b, c, d` in scope in the first four equations for `func`.

Comment: I have to say, that i edited the indentation for stackoverflow, because it didn't show it properly. So the code for the compiler looks a bit different.
But now i know that i don't have to use tabs and that where can't work for multiple functions.